# error during mysql db connection in localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

when I am trying to connect mySql data base from cmd it giving some error like -

`c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqladmin -u root password 123123`
mysqladmin: connect to server at `localhost` failed
error:Access denied for user root@localhost (using password : NO)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

`mysqladmin -u root -p PASSWORD`

?

Comment: how can I reset my root password??

Comment: Tr this one: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks wrong to me, just like Roberto said. You could also use this

```
mysqladmin -u root -h localhost -p
```

It should then ask you for the password. This way you can be sure that only a wrongly entered PW prevents you from connecting.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p
```

and it will prompt you for a password. If you need to enter the password directly via the command line ( say you need to write a script), you should be able to do that with:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p123123
```